# Having variable issue

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, flash-cs5

I'm having trouble with a variable being update. Below, my Main document function has my level equaling 1 and generating multiple tiles. It does equal 1, but I have the if statement saying to go up a level if a var equals true.

```
    public var enemiesDefeated:Boolean = false;        
    addChild(level);
    //START THE GAME AT LEVEL 1//
    level.levelNumber = 1;
    if (enemiesDefeated == true){
        level.levelNumber += 1;
    }
    var tileh:int = 60;

    for (var Y:int=0; Y<floor.length; Y++)
    {
        for (var X:int=0; X<floor[Y].length; X++)
        {
                var cell:MovieClip = new Tile(X,Y);
            cell.gotoAndStop(floor[Y][X]);
            cell.x = ((X-Y)*tileh)+365;
            cell.y = ((X+Y)*tileh/2)+70;
            addChild(cell);

            cell.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseclick);
            cell.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onGame);
            cell.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addEnemy);
        }
    }
```

The variable enemiesDefeated is turned to true in my onGame function if I destroy all the enemies, however, the level is staying at level 1 after enemiesDefeated equals true.

```
function onGame(event:Event){

    ...

    if (enemy.enemyHP <= 0) 
        {
             removeChild(enemy);
             enemy.enemyDead = true;
             enemiesDefeated = true;
             trace("Dead", enemy.enemyDead);
        }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Provide more code as it is not visible in which function you check `enemiesDefeated` variable. Most likely you don't call the checking function **after** the `enemiesDefeated` variable becomes `true`.

Comment: enemiesDefeated is a public function. I figured making it public would make it accessible to every function in my main. I will update the code.

Comment: `enemiesDefeated`is not a function but a variable. Did you try to `trace(enemiesDefeated);` before your `if`?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant var. It traces as false, then when the enemyHP is 0, it traces as true, but the stage doesn't change. I'm guessing because When I declared levelNumber as 1, it'll just stay that way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure onGame gets called for every cell for every frame. Is that intended?

Comment: Correct! There are other code in there that pertains to each individual tile. Maybe that might be the cause?